# How can I reference FileInfo type inside a function?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a `FileInfo[] fileInfos` class and I want to use it inside a function to return the files inside a folder to be executed in a copy function

```
    FileInfo[] fileInfos = new DirectoryInfo(FolderLocation).GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
                        IEnumerable<FileInfo> files = fileInfos.Where((f) => f.CreationTime <= FileDateLessThan);
```

I want to use it inside this function

```
    string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles("Your Path");  
    foreach (var filename in filePaths)  
    {  
        string file = filename.ToString();  

        //Do your job with "file"  
        string str = "Your Destination"+file.ToString(),=.Replace("Your Path");  
        if (!File.Exists(str))  
        {  
            File.Copy(file , str);  
        }  
    }
```

I tried to use it but I get the error `FileInfo is a type`

```
if (ExecutableAction == "COPY")
                    {
                        string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(FileInfo[] fileInfos);
                        foreach (var filename in filePaths)
                        {
                            string file = filename.ToString();

                            //Do your job with "file"  
                            string str = TargetfolderLocation + file.ToString().Replace(FileInfo[] fileInfos);
                            if (!File.Exists(str))
                            {
                                File.Copy(file, str);
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

What is the proper way to reference the FileInfo type in my function

Comment: Perhaps you should look up [the documentation for `String.Replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=netframework-4.8). Hint: It takes two `string`s or two `char`s, not one `string` or an array of `FileInfo`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some points to consider.

**Get the files**

You can replace the first block of code with:

```cs
var files = new DirectoryInfo(FolderLocation).EnumerateFiles("*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
    .Where(f => f.CreationTime <= FileDateLessThan);
```

To return an `IEnumerable<FileInfo>` assigned to the `files` variable in a single query instead of two.

Note that, the [FileInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo?view=netframework-4.8) class encapsulates properties like the `Name` property which returns the name of the file including the extension, and the `FullName` property which returns the path of the file including it's `Name`.

Also, the `FileInfo` class contains methods like `CopyTo` and `MoveTo` to copy/move a file to a different destination. Meaning, no need to use methods from another class (like `File.Copy`, and `File.Move`) to perform these operations.

**Copy them**

As I understand, you want to copy `files` to a new destination. So, all what you need to do:

```cs
//For example:
var destination = @"c:\temp\";

files.ToList().ForEach(f => 
f.CopyTo(Path.Combine(destination, f.Name), true)); //true to overwrite a file with the 
                                                    //same name in the destination if any.
```

Or, to copy the file only if it does not exist in the destination:

```cs
files.ToList().ForEach(f =>
{
    var s = Path.Combine(destination, f.Name);
    if (!File.Exists(s))
        f.CopyTo(s);
});
```

Or without using the `File` class:

```cs
files.Where(x => new FileInfo(Path.Combine(destination, x.Name)).Exists == false)
    .ToList().ForEach(f => f.CopyTo(Path.Combine(destination, f.Name)));
```

Note the [Path.Combine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine?view=netframework-4.8) function which is used here - instead of a string concatenation - to create a valid path.

**All-in-One**

You can *combine* everything in just:

```cs
private void TheCaller()
{
    //..
    //..

    new DirectoryInfo(FolderLocation).EnumerateFiles("*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
        .Where(f => f.CreationTime <= FileDateLessThan &&
        !File.Exists(Path.Combine(destination, f.Name)))
        .ToList().ForEach(f => f.CopyTo(Path.Combine(destination, f.Name)));
}
```

**Last Stop**

- The `Directory.GetFiles(..)` function returns a string array so no need to do `string file = filename.ToString();` since the `filename` is already of string type.
- You should instantiate an object of a *Type* to use it and not use a *Type* as an instance.

That's it all.